# edit() crashes R on Mac OS X when trying to edit data frame

Tags: r, macos

Does anybody have an idea for what I need to reconfigure?
I'm on Mac OS X Version 9.0 (10601.1.56.2) and R version 3.2.2

The edit() function seems to work for simple objects and functions
R segfaults if I try editing a data frame however

```
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
Copyright (C) 2015 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)

[R.app GUI 1.66 (6996) x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0]

> x <- rnorm(10)
> edit(x)
 [1]  0.96793711  0.46449359  0.05136297  0.38438847  0.73942230 -1.12691486 -0.84414357 -3.67522840 -1.03864446
[10] -0.37159107
> x <- data.frame(x)
> edit(x)

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x10db0, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: as.matrix.data.frame(format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE))
 2: as.matrix(format.data.frame(x, digits = digits, na.encode = FALSE))
 3: print.data.frame(x)
 4: function (x, ...) UseMethod("print")(x)

Possible actions:
1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
2: normal R exit
3: exit R without saving workspace
4: exit R saving workspace
Selection:
```

Comment: (1) When you say "Version 9" of OS X, presumably you mean 10.9 (Mavericks)?, (2) Have you installed X11?, (3) I can't reproduce this problem...

Comment: Works for me in 10.10.5 and XQuartz 2.7.7 (xorg-server 1.15.2). Try an upgrade?

Comment: Runs fine on 10.11.1 beta, R3.2.2, XQuartz 2.7.7

Comment: I'm not sure what I copied to report on the OS, but I'm on 10.10.5 Yosemite.  I just reinstalled X11(XQuartz 2.7.7), and yesterday I reinstalled R.  I still have the problem.